# Not able to execute HTTP/1.x requests for gRPC service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to execute an HTTP/1.x request for a gRPC service, but getting below error.

```
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: Unexpected HTTP/1.x request: GET /author/1 
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:109) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.readClientPrefaceString(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:317) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:247) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:453) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

My .proto file is as below.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.myapp.grpc_server.proto;

option java_multiple_files = true;

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

message Book {
  int32 book_id = 1;
  string title = 2;
  float book_price = 3;
  int32 pages = 4;
  int32 author_id = 5;
}

message Author {
  int32 author_id = 1;
  string first_name = 2;
  string last_name = 3;
  string gender = 4;
  int32 book_id = 5;
}

service BookAuthorService {
  //unary - synchronous - client will send one request and one response will be received.
  rpc getAuthor(Author) returns (Author) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/author/{id}"
    };
  }
}
```

[image: My proto directory containing my .proto file along with annotations.proto and http.proto files copied from googleapis github.com/googleapis/googleapis]

```
My proto directory containing my .proto file along with annotations.proto and http.proto files copied from googleapis github.com/googleapis/googleapis
```

[image: generated sources after compiling]

```
generated sources after compiling
```

GrpcService Class

```
package com.myapp.grpcserver.service;

import com.myapp.grpc_server.proto.Author;
import com.myapp.grpc_server.proto.Book;
import com.myapp.grpc_server.proto.BookAuthorServiceGrpc;
import com.myapp.grpcserver.setup.TempDB;
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;
import net.devh.boot.grpc.server.service.GrpcService;

@GrpcService
public class BookAuthorService extends BookAuthorServiceGrpc.BookAuthorServiceImplBase {

    @Override
    public void getAuthor(Author request, StreamObserver<Author> responseObserver) {
        TempDB.authors.stream()
                .filter(author -> author.getAuthorId() == request.getAuthorId())
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(responseObserver::onNext);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

I am firing a GET Request using browser on the defined end-point but getting above error. Please suggest where I am wrong and what I need to do. Please share any working examples in Java as official docs of grpc-gateway is in Go.

Comment: GRPC doesn't natively support HTTP1x only HTTP2. If you want to use HTTP1 you need some gateway in between that will do the conversion.

Comment: Probably simply missing the domain and any prefixed protocol. It cannot guess the domain.

Comment: @M.Deinum - That is what I have tried doing by referring to the docs at https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway
The Docs are in Go reference and tried doing the same for Java, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Java gRPC does not support any notion of converting from http1 to http2 and you can not add it to it by utilizing grpc-gateway. You CAN use grpc-gateway to create a separate proxy that can handle this conversion, but it would run as it's own separate process, independent of your Java application.

You may have adopted some Go specific instructions that have grpc-gateway embedded in the gRPC server, but this is only possible for Go implementations. I would recommend taking another look at the instructions and build your standalone gateway.